# Using params keyword with dynamic type arguments

Tags: c#, generics

I've declared an interface with `Add` method to add new item, 2 classes `TopicModel` and `CommentModel` to store data.

I've re-write the code in console mode, like this:

```
interface IAction
{
    void Add<T>(params T[] t) where T : class;
}

class TopicModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
}

class CommentModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

class Topic : IDisposable, IAction
{
    public void Add<T>(params T[] t) where T : class
    {
        var topic = t[0] as TopicModel;
        var comment = t[1] as CommentModel;

        // do stuff...
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class MainClass
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var t = new TopicModel { Id = "T101", Author = "Harry" };
        var c = new CommentModel { Id = "C101", Content = "Comment 01" };

        using (var topic = new Topic())
        {
            //topic.Add(t, c);
        }
    }
}
```

The line `topic.Add(t, c)` gave me error message:

> The type arguments for method 'Topic.Add(params T[])' cannot be
>   inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Then, I've tried again with:

```
topic.Add(c, c) // Good :))
topic.Add(t, t, t); // That's okay =))
```

That's my problem. I want the method accepts 2 different types (`TopicModel` and `CommentModel`).

And, I don't want to declare:

```
interface IAction
{
    void Add(TopicModel t, CommentModel c);
}
```

because another classes can re-use `Add` method within different argument types.

So, my question is: how to change `params T[] t` to accept multiple argument types?

Comment: The code is simply not generic.  You hope that the caller passes arguments of the correct type but there is no way for the compiler to actually verify and enforce that.  You might as well use *object*.

Comment: What are the types that the `Add` method is expected to work with? For example, can it work for the `int` type? In the body of the `Add` method, you are explicitly casting the first parameter to `TopicModel` and the second to `CommentModel`, this means that you are expecting these specific types. You need to add more context to the question about what the `Add` method is supposed to do.

Comment: @YacoubMassad It gave me no error if I changed `topic.Add(t, c)` to `topic.Add(t, t)` or `topic.Add(c, c)`

Comment: @HansPassant You mean `object array`, don't you?

Comment: Sure.  Or dynamic[], saves you from having to use `as` and fret about what to do when it generates null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TopicModel et CommentModel must inherit same class Or implement same interface. Try This :

```
interface IAction
{
    void Add<T>(params T[] t) where T : IModel;
}

class IModel
{
}

class TopicModel : IModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
}

class CommentModel : IModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}

class Topic : IDisposable, IAction
{
    public void Add<T>(params T[] t) where T : IModel
    {
        var topic = t[0] as TopicModel;
        var comment = t[1] as CommentModel;

        Console.WriteLine("Topic witch ID={0} added",topic.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Commment witch ID={0} added", comment.Id);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        TopicModel t = new TopicModel { Id = "T101", Author = "Harry" };
        CommentModel c = new CommentModel { Id = "C101", Content = "Comment 01" };

        using (var topic = new Topic())
        {
            topic.Add<IModel>(t, c);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```